# Single ImageView in OpenGL live wallpaper Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textview, imageview, live-wallpaper

I wanted to know if there was a way to have an ImageView for the background image of an OpenGL live wallpaper for Android. I know that surface views cannot be used, but what is the equivalent? Because I would also like to add a TextView.

For example; You can set a specific background image in a regular app as well as a TextView but it won't let you within a live wallpaper. It says LinearLayout is undefined for class Wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any widgets for the openGL. In Live wallpaper for 2D graphics the SurfaceView is used and for 3D, there is a GLSurfaceview.

For 2D graphics you will have to draw on the canvas and for 3D graphics there is a GL object with different versions.